# How to link to a specific part of the page with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to link my footer to a specific part of other page but i don't know how to do it in CodeIgniter. 
I know in native php we have to do something like this 
`<h2>Nosotros</h2>
 <ul>
<li><a href="nosotros.php#QuienesSomos"> ¿Quiénes Somos?</a></li>`

And in the other class we have this

```
<div class="present" id="QuienesSomos">
```

I understand that, my question is, how do i implement that to a controller? My controller is this

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class nosotros_controller extends CI_Controller{
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}
function index(){
    $datav["titulopagina"] ="Nosotros";
    $this->load->view('includes/header',$datav);
    $this->load->view('inicio/banner');
    $this->load->view('nosotros/nosotros');
    $this->load->view('includes/footer');
}
}
?>
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you would put the link in your footer and or navigation bar and the div in your view. Look at the HTML that is generated, then look at how you are implementing it with your views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you can make route for specific footer**

```
//inside config/routes.php
$route['footer'] = 'controller/method_name';
//controller
function method_name(){
 $this->load->view('includes/footer');
}
//view 
<a href="<?php echo base_url('auth/logout'); ?>">QuienesSomos</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put following code In your `nosotros` view file (nosotros.php or other file that you want to link)

```
<div class="present" id="QuienesSomos">
```

and following code In your `footer` view file (footer.php)

```
<a href="nosotros/#QuienesSomos"> ¿Quiénes Somos?</a>
```

`nosotros` here is the controler path of the (other) page

Also, take a look at [Views documentation](https://devdocs.io/codeigniter~3/general/views).